# Google chrome not being served scripts and css from MVC5 local debugging

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2015, localhost, asp.net-mvc-5

### The Issue:

I am trying to debug an MVC5 app on visual studio 2015. I cannot debug in google chrome because it is not being served any css and javascript files from iis express (I assume). Debugging in internet explorer has no problem.

I am getting 404 errors when I look in the console. An example is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:55254/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js

Other browsers are out of the question due to it policy.

When the app is deployed on a server to IIS, it will run on chrome with no issues.

My coworker, using EXACTLY the same code base (run from local share on my machine), can debug in chrome with no issues.

This leads me to believe that the issue lies with my IIS express settings or chrome itself.

Even trying to debug the MVC 5 demo in chrome leads to the same issue meaning that its nothing to do with my code.

Similarly, mvc core simply will not debug on my machine, it immediately halts whereas it runs fine on my coworker's box.

### What I've tried:

- reinstall chrome
- reinstall iis
- reset iis to defaults
- reinstall visual studio
- reinstall all vs extentions
- update IIS

So far, nothing has corrected the issue. I do not want to have to rebuild the machine however I am running out of options. If anyone has seen this issue before, I would be very greatful to hear the answer

Comment: Please copy the IIS Express config file under C:\Users\UserName\Documents\IISExpress\config from your coworker's machine to replace the files on your machine, which could help us confirm whether this issue related to the IIS Express settings or not. Please backup the files before replace it. Then please compare the Chrome version and settings with your coworker's, it helps us troubleshoot whether it is a Chrome settings version.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and at the time it did nothing however, after returning to my desk this morning, it seems to have worked (for now at least). I may still order a rebuild over Christmas to ensure that this does not happen again though!